# Kubuntu 22.04 wake on usb printer

Tags: usb, kubuntu, printing, wakeup

I have an Asus E410KA with kubuntu 22.04 on it. Also I have a usb printer connected to it. What I want is to be able to wake up the laptop when I turn on the printer. On an old laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 I managed to achieve this by running a script with "echo enabled /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup". On this new laptop I got nothing.

grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/wakeup:disabled

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled

On lsusb the printer is *bus 001 device 009*

On grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product the printer is */sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/*

Trying  sudo echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup gives Permission error

If I put the mouse in the same physical port, it will wake the computer up; it appears as wakeup enabled.

So what changed in 22.04 or what workaround do you know of?

Thanks
Naim

Edit:

naim@asus-printer:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 322e:2113 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 VGAUVC WebCam

Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0482:04fb Kyocera Corp. FS-1041

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

naim@asus-printer:~$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/product:FS-1041

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/product:USB Receiver

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/product:USB2.0 VGAUVC WebCam

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:xHCI Host Controller

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller

naim@asus-printer:~$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power/wakeup:disabled

/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/wakeup:enabled

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled

/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled

Note 1: if I enable /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup then when I send the system to sleep (suspend to ram) it enters sleep and wakes up in a matter of seconds (even when no usb devices are attached). So enabling all /sys/bus/usb/devices/... doesn't work.
Note 2: the system wakes from sleep on mouse (Logitech MX Anywhere 2) motion (no matter in which usb port it is plugged).

Now, I am not necessarily keen to make it wake on printer-turn-on if there is a way to make it wake on ac_power on (like the laptop should enter in sleep mode when there is no ac_power and should wake up when ac_power will be back on), maybe something to tinker about acpi/acpid... I don't really know. I found something in /usr/share/doc/acpid/examples/ac [and ac.sh] but I have no knowledge of how to  (at least try) make it work.

Contents of ac file:

## /etc/acpid/events/ac

## This detects changes to AC power status, and passes them to

## /etc/acpi/ac.sh for further processing.

## Optionally you can specify the placeholder %e. It will pass

## through the whole kernel event message to the program you've

## specified.

event=ac_adapter
action=/etc/acpi/ac.sh

Contents of ac.sh:
#!/bin/sh

## /etc/acpid/ac.sh

## Detect loss of AC power and regaining of AC power, and take action

## appropriatly.

## On my laptop anyway, this script doesn't not get different parameters for

## loss of power and regained power. So, I have to use a separate program to

## tell what the adapter status is.

## This uses the spicctrl program for probing the sonypi device.

BACKLIGHT=$(spicctrl -B)

if on_ac_power; then
# Now on AC power.

```
    # Tell longrun to go crazy.
    longrun -f performance
    longrun -s 0 100

    # Turn up the backlight unless it's up far enough.
    if [ "$BACKLIGHT" -lt 108 ]; then
            spicctrl -b 108
    fi
```

else
# Now off AC power.

```
    # Tell longrun to be a miser.
    longrun -f economy
    longrun -s 0 50 # adjust to suite..

    # Don't allow the screen to be too bright, but don't turn the
    # backlight _up_ on removal, and don't turn it all the way down, as
    # that is unusable on my laptop in most conditions. Adjust to
    # taste.
    if [ "$BACKLIGHT" -gt 68 ]; then
            spicctrl -b 68
    fi
```

fi

Since my first post on this matter I wiped Kubuntu, installed Slackware_15-64, spent about 6 hours to make it charge the battery only to 60% (it's important) and keep that over reboot only to find out that for the sake of god I can not share the printer (kyocera FS-1041) over local network so anybody could print from an android phone. Then I wiped the slackware and reinstalled Kubuntu 22.04 to try to make it work as desired. At least now I can print when the laptop is on.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`echo` can't use sudo privileges.

A workaround for that is piping `echo` to `tee`.

So the command would be `echo enabled | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup`

See if this solves the permission error. If it gives another error, update your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Emre,  it did not work. Also, because the printer is in a hard accessible place and I had to disconnect and reconnect the printer to the laptop, the printer's bus-dev has changed to 1-10. So I believe this will change with any reboot or dis/reconnection. Still had the permission error. What I remember is that before trying to enable echo on 1-9 I did it with usb1 which worked in the way that it got enabled but then the laptop was not staying in sleep mode (entered in sleep only for a few seconds).

Comment: And the old laptop had Ubuntu 16.04 not 18 as I previously wrote (I forgot maybe due to not interacting with it for a long time since was set up as a cups server :)).